# What the easiest way to move selected lines up or down in emacs?

Tags: emacs

I've already selected some lines in emacs. What is the easiest way to move those lines (whole line) up or down?

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Move line/region up and down in emacs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2423834/move-line-region-up-and-down-in-emacs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

drag-stuff-mode is probably what you need.